# MSAL.js acquireTokenSilent on Azure AD B2C with Microsoft Account (login.live.com) framebusting

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-account, framebusting

There is a problem with `login.live.com` that prevents acquiring access tokens with [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) for Azure AD B2C with the Identity Provider Microsoft Account.

When the iframe (`msalRenewFrame…`) tries to authenticate at `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf`, `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf` attempts to ‘framebust’ (navigate the parent of the iframe which is the main site). Chrome shows this warning:

> Frame with URL
>   'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=… attempted to
>   navigate its top-level window with URL
>   'http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard'. Navigating the top-level window
>   from a cross-origin iframe will soon require that the iframe has
>   received a user gesture. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5851021045661696.
>
> DoSubmit @ oauth20_authorize…
>   onload @ oauth20_authorize…

This causes the main site to redirect, which turns `acquireTokenSilent` into `acquireTokenBoisterous`. Just kidding.

I tried to sandbox the `msalRenewFrame…` with `ifr.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts")` according to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp. Now the main site does not redirect away, but now Chrome shows an error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL
>   'http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard' from frame with URL
>   'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=… The frame
>   attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the
>   flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or
>   'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

I assume this framebusting happens for compatibility reasons (we all know how redirect heavy logging in into Microsoft services is). I am afraid this is no easy fix. But Chrome will break it soon anyway so maybe the team behind `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf` is already on it. Until then Azure AD B2C in combination with Live Accounts and MSAL.js is broken and cannot be used.

I have posted this finding at [issue 267 of MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/267) but since this is not an MSAL.js problem, I am posting it here too. I hope someone of the Microsoft Account Team sees it and can maybe provide more information.

---

This is how I instantiate MSAL:

```
public initAndHandleRedirects() {
  const authority = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/${environment.msalConfig.tenant}/${environment.msalConfig.signUpSignInPolicy}`;
  this.clientApplication = new UserAgentApplication(environment.msalConfig.clientId, authority,
    function (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        console.warn(`got new ${tokenType} token: ${token}`);
      }
    },
    {
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
      redirectUri: environment.msalConfig.redirectUri,
      logger: new Logger(this.log)
    }
  );

  if (this.authenticated) {
    console.warn(`User: ${this.idToken['extension_Nickname']} (${this.idToken['sub']})`);
  }
}
```

and this is how I try to get an access token

```
public getAccessToken(): Observable<string> {
  const that = this;
  const acquireTokenPromise = this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(environment.msalConfig.scopes);
  return fromPromise(acquireTokenPromise);
}
```

Scopes is `[ 'https://....onmicrosoft.com/.../user_impersonation' ]`

Comment: Can you example your flow a little more?  Seems like you're trying to have the user authentication to B2C w/ the Microsoft Identity Provider and then request an access token from the Microsoft Identity Provider, correct?

Comment: I need an access token and try to get it with invoking acquireTokenSilent on the MSAL.js library.

Comment: Can you share how you are creating an instance of the MSAL `ClientApplication`?

Comment: Sure :) I added it to the question.

Comment: .  That looks good.  Now how are trying to get an access token?  Code please .  Are you using the same instance of `this.clientApplication`?

Comment: Yes, it is the same instance.

Comment: I've been trying to get this working and hit this issue and I think, on balance, the issue does lie with the MSAL library;  the library should work with what the service provides.  It is disappointing that other services work okay with acquireTokenSilent but the MSA service does not.

Comment: Hi @halllo 
Did you get any solution to this problem. I am facing same problem where this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent is not returning anything to me.
Any alternative to get around this?

Comment: @Raj unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

You can [request access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens) tokens **from** B2C, for scopes defined in B2C.

Example:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=<yourPolicyId>&client_id=<appID_of_your_client_application>&nonce=anyRandomValue&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri_of_your_client_application>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fcontoso.onmicrosoft.com%2Fnotes%2Fread&response_type=code
```

You **can not** request access **from** an Identity Provider (**IDP**) for a B2C authentication.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But the MSAL.js library tries to acquire a token from `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf` when I invoke `acquireTokenSilent` (which is for access tokens) and then the browser redirects away (which is bad) and gives me an access token over the redirect uri (which I expected inside the iframe).

Comment: MSAL tries to get a token from where it has been configured to  @halllo

Comment: I though the whole point of external identity providers was to only configure them in the B2C portal and not in the client.